# $auth is undefined in axios.js (nux.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm very new to vue.js and nuxt.js and now I'm using auth configuration inside the nux.config.js file as below:

```
auth: {
redirect: {
  login: '/auth',
  logout: '/auth',
  home: '/jobs',
  user: '/jobs',
},
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      logout: false,
      login: {
        url: '/auth/authenticate',
        method: 'post',
        propertyName: 'jwtToken',
      },
      user: {
        url: '/auth/me',
        method: 'get',
        propertyName: false,
      },
    },
    tokenRequired: true,
    tokenType: 'Bearer',
  },
},
plugins: ['@/plugins/auth.js', '@/plugins/search-engine'],
```

Beside that I'm trying to handling some errors inside the axios.js like below:

```
import { Message } from 'element-ui'

export default function ({ $axios, $auth, redirect }) {

  $axios.onError((error) => {
console.info({ error: $auth.logout() })
if (!error.response) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(
    `There was an error contacting '${
      error.config ? error.config.url : 'unknown'
    }'`
  )
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(error)
}

Message.closeAll()
if (error.response.status === 401) {
  $auth.logout()
  return redirect('/auth')
}

if ([422, 404, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
  Message({
    type: 'error',
    message: 'Uh oh! An error occured. Please try again.',
    duration: 5000,
  })
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(error)
}})
```

when I'm trying to execute the program I'm receiving an error by console.info({ error: $auth })

that the $auth is undefined. and after that I cannot use the property of undefined. for example I wanted to use the $auth.logout()

Please help

Comment: If `$auth` is undefined, I would first check for a problem in your `nuxt.config.js`.  Double-check your config, including the order in which you are defining your modules and plugins

Comment: Are you including the auth module in your `nuxt.config.js`? like this... `modules:[ '@nuxtjs/auth']` https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/